# Rmarkdown PDF won't render less than equal to U+2264

Tags: utf-8, r-markdown

So, here's the problem, I want to knit this to a PDF:

```
---
title: "Render"
output: 
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
  word_document: default
---
## R Markdown

Test ≤
```

If I knit to HTML, this works. If I knit to PDF using xelatex, the ≤ is blank. Any idea how to fix this? Is this a font issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML UTF-8](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_math.asp) operators or [Latex math mode](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols#Relation_operators) symbols. Whereby the HTML fits for both, HTML and PDF compiling. Try this in your rmarkdown doc:

```
Test ≤

### HTML
Test &le; or Test &#8804;   or Test &#x2264;

### Latex MathMode
Test $\leq$

or

Test $\leqslant$

Compare: $x\leq y$

and 

x$\leq$y
```

Comment: PDF will only compile in math mode, HTML will compile in HTML format, and the raw character input from the keyboard doesn't compile in either.

Comment: If you are inside a code block you may need to use $\\leq$